# How to zip many n-th level subdirectories, without their top (parent) dir?

Tags: shell, find, zip, pushd

in such a filesystem structure:

```
root/
    |
    container1/
    |         |
    |         subdir2/
    |                |
    |                subdir3/
    |                       |
    |                       subdir4/
    |                              |
    |                              file1
    |                              file2
    |                              subdir5/
    container2/
              |...
```

**I need to zip everything:**

- under `/subdir4/``
- without the `/subdir4/` itself
- in all potential `/container/` subdirs of the `root/`directory
- name the zip the same as the parent folder of the contents being zipped (in this case, it would be "subdir4.zip")

**Please bear in mind:**

- these are not the real names of dirs and subdirs, it's just an approximation
- I am using ZSH on a Mac OSX
- I am quite new to Unix/Linux scripting

I would really like a shell-agnostic, simple, loop kind of solution so I can learn as much as possible and be flexible in modifying this solution for other potential cases.

**Here is what I have tried so far**, as suggested by friends:

```
find . -mindepth 5 -maxdepth 5 -type d -exec sh -c '
pushd "$0/..";zip -rFS "$(basename "$0").zip" "$(basename "$0")";popd ' {} \;
```

In the meantime, I have learned that this solution has the following drawbacks:

- $0 should not be used as positional parameter because it is used in error reporting and/or as the shell script name (in my case, it's just a string)
- `basename` and `dirname` are best avoided if using bash (read more [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue18/bash.html))
- this syntax, with `... {} \;`invokes as many shells as there are results, supposedly not efficient way of doing this type of operation

**I should have been using:**

- $1 in my positional parameters
- `... ;popd ' sh {} +`

That one is supposed to get all the results in a sort-of an "array/list" and apply the commands within the string passed to the `sh` all at once.

Thanks!

**BONUS POINTS:** :)

- can I name the resulting .zip same as `/subdir3/` instead of as `/subdir4/` from this hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to create the system command to execute

```
find * -mindepth 5 -maxdepth 5 -type d  | awk -F"/" '{system( "cd "$0"; zip -rF "$NF".zip *")}'
```

The `-F` splits the line on / , `$0` represents the complete line and `$NF` has your actual directory name.  There is no popd required since the system command executes in its own shell, and the parent shell stays in the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it! However, won't this solution include `subdir4/` as well? I see that you first `cd` into the --parent-- of the subdir whose contents I wish to zip (`..."cd "$0"/.."`)? I tried to run this but nothing happened, just got my prompt back

Comment: If you want to exclude subdir4 in the zip, then just do a `cd $0` . I will edit the answer

Comment: I tried with and without /.. but nothing happens. As mentioned, I just get my prompt back after half a second.